# Maximising a function of $t$ for a compound Poisson Process

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, expected-value, poisson-process

I was trying to solve the following question from Sheldon Ross, Introduction to Probability Models.

> The number of missing items in a certain location, call it $X$, is a Poisson
> random variable with mean $\lambda$. When searching the location, each item will
> independently be found after an exponentially distributed time with rate $\mu$. A
> reward of $R$ is received for each item found, and a searching cost of $C$ per unit
> of search time is incurred. Suppose that you search for a fixed time $t$ and then
> stop. i) Find your total expected return.
> ii) Find the value of $t$ that maximizes the total expected return.

In order to solve i), I have done the following:

> Let $Z$ be an exponential variable with parameter $\mu$. Define the collection of independent identically distributed indicator random variables
> $$Y_{i}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> 1 & \text { if }Z<t \\
> 0 & \text { if }Z>t
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> $Y_i$ essentially denotes if the $i^{th}$ item has been found. Then, if $X(t)$ denotes the total number of items found in time $t$, it follows that
> $$X(t):=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}Y_i$$
> where each $Y_i$ is iid and $N(t)$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$. Then,
> $$E[X(t)]=\lambda t E[Y_1]=\lambda t P(Z<t)=\lambda t(1-e^{-\mu t})$$
> and so
> $$E[RX(t)-Ct]=RE[X(t)]-Ct=R\lambda t (1-e^{-\mu t}) -Ct.$$

My problem is the fact that ii) requires me to maximise the value of $t$ obtained above. When I plot the graph or put it on Wolframalpha, it appears that there is no global maxima. So I am not sure if the expectation I calculated is wrong or I am just unable to calculate the maxima. Any help would be appreciated.